# Insert pages from a PDF file to fit at the entire page using \includepdf

Tags: margins, pdfpages

I want to insert every page of a PDF file so I used:

```
\documentclass{customized_class}
\begin{document}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\includepdf[fitpaper,pages={-}]{filename}
\end{document}
```

This works fine when using any standard classes like report. Now I have to use a customized class for the document. This causes that the pages do not cover a whole page but are slightly over the edges so that I have margins to the left and to the bottom of every page. So that the option `fitpaper` doesn't seem to work correctly.

[Link to download the class file "mpreport.cls"](http://wdok.cs.uni-magdeburg.de/studium-und-lehre/hinweise-und-vorlagen/wdok-diplom.tar.gz) - You can open it with WinRAR.

There are other files as well to create that document which are less important for this question.

Is there a way to change the class just for all the pages I will include or maybe just the pre-settings of the borders or margins created by the class file?

Maybe I could also use `\includegraphics`? I tried it but couldn't figure out how one option will include every page of the PDF file on a new page in the document and covering the whole page as well so that the page number will be left out.

This is how it looks like after I included the "pdfpages" documentation.

[image: First page of the "pdfpages" documentation]

Comment: The `pdfpages` documentation has many options and mentions how you can manually scale your imported pages. See http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf

Comment: Well I don't want to scale the imported page. I want to use the option "fitpaper" which can be found in the document you linked so they cover the whole page.

Comment: I understand you want to use `fitpaper`.  But if no one can come up with a simple fix (and since you are using a customized class, it may be difficult to understand where the problem arises), then scaling each page may be your only workable option.

Comment: You should post your class file (maybe uploaded externally). By default, `\includepdf` creates pages with the `empty` pagestyle, and that's why there's no page numbering. Does your class redefine this pagestyle?

Comment: Ok, I added the link in the question. You can open the package with WinRAR. The name of the class file is "mpreport.cls".

Comment: @T.Verron: I don't need the page numbering for the PDF pages I'll include otherwise I would use the option `pagecommand={}`. I did use that option for the picture I included in the main question. That's why there is a the page number 40 at the bottom right of the page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a option which helps (**offset-option**):

```
\includepdf[page={-},offset=<offset in x>mm <offset in y>mm]{file_name}
```

Comment: For the case of "twoside" book documentclass, it did not work. Any suggestion?

Comment: For future readers: for me `pgffor` helped: instead of `\includepdf[fitpaper=true,pages=1-100]{filename}` I used `\foreach \p in {1,...,100} {\includepdf[fitpaper=true,pages=\p]{filename}}`. Including only one at a time seems to make it work.