# Adding PDF pages with \includegraphics using a loop

Tags: graphics, pdf, loops

I need to include PDF pages with `\includegraphics`. I know there is the package `\usepackage{pdfpages}`. So this is what I have:

```
\begin{picture}(0,0)(75,272.5)
\put(0,0){\frame{\includegraphics[page=i]{pdf_file_name}}}
\end{picture}
```

I need those dimensions so that the PDF page covers the whole page it is included.
Now I want to add every page in a row of that PDF file. How can I create a loop which does that for me? Is there a key for the last page of the file? I have no idea about using `\while` `\for` or `\if` in this case. If you have any further documentation about it that would great.

Example:

```
\for i=1 to i=last_page_of_pdf_file
{
\begin{picture}(0,0)(75,272.5)
\put(0,0){\frame{\includegraphics[page=i]{pdf_file_name}}}
\end{picture}
\newpage
}
```

I asked somthing similar using `\includepdf`. - [Link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125135/insert-pages-from-a-pdf-file-to-fit-at-the-entire-page-using-includepdf)

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit why you don't just use `pdfpages` (maybe with the `picturecommand` option of the `\includepdf` command)?

Comment: Well I tried but I couldn't figure out to change the page layout so that the option `fitpaper` would work and the PDF page covers the whole page. - (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125135/insert-pages-from-a-pdf-file-to-fit-at-the-entire-page-using-includepdf)

Comment: This is what I used: `\includepdf[page={-},frame,pagecommand={},fitpaper]{file_name}`. But as I have a customized class there is always a margin to the right and to the bottom of the page which shouldn't be there with the option `fitpaper`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The tricky part is to get the maximum number of pages in a PDF file. If a file is included in pdfTeX, then it sets a primitive `\pdflastximagepages` with the number of pages in the included PDF file.

Thus the following example defines the macro `\getpdfpages`. It includes the first page in a temporary box. Then it sets the LaTeX counter `pdfpages` to the value of `\pdflastximagepages`.

Looping can be done in many, many ways. The example just uses one of them, `\foreach` of `pgf`/`TikZ`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcounter{pdfpages}
\newcommand*{\getpdfpages}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \sbox0{% 
      \includegraphics{#1}%
      \setcounter{pdfpages}{\pdflastximagepages}%
    }%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
  \getpdfpages{t.pdf}
  \foreach \x in {1,...,\value{pdfpages}} {
    % your code for page \x of t.pdf goes here
    \includegraphics[page=\x]{t.pdf}%
  }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Cool, I wasn't aware of `\pdflastximagepages`. Very useful!

Comment: Note that using `\pdflastximagepages` after `\includegraphics` should be handeled with care as `\includegraphics` doesn't always call `\pdfximage`.

Comment: @StephanLehmke: For example, MetaPost PostScript files (MPS files) are handled differently and processed by some ConTeXt macros of Hans Hagen without `\pdfximage`.